# type ahead search in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have a  grid with collection of student

```
public class Student
{
public string First{get;set;}
public string Last{get;set;}
public int Age{get;set;}
}

MyGrid.ItemsSource= new List<Student>(){new Student{First="First1",Last="Last1",Age=1},
new Student{First="First2",Last="Last2",Age=2}},
new Student{First="First3",Last="Last3",Age=3}},
new Student{First="First4",Last="Last4",Age=4}},};
```

Now after the page or grid is loaded user will simply type in some characters and the application has to select the specific row that matches the user input with first or last name.

This is exact similar to what we see in windows explorer or visual studio just type in to select folder in Win Explorer or a .cs file in visualstudio.

how do we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two day research I finally found the answer.

it is very simple to achieve this functionality.

Set an attached property to desired property name and it works magically.

```
TextSearch.TextPath="First"
```

Comment: This attached property is applicable any ItemsControl like Listbox, DataGrid.... 
I am not sure why this is down posted but it is a valid question

Answer (score -1):

Your `DataGrid` would be as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Key}" Header="Key"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Header="Value"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

If you want something like `Key` x `Value` you do not need to create a `model` for this, the `.NET Framework 4.5` already has a specific class for this, the class `Dictionary <TKey, TValue>` (`TKey` is the type of key data and `TValue` is the type of value data, so you would need a `C#` code like (or equal to) the following:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
     {"Key1","Value1"},
     {"Key2","Value2"},
     {"Key3","Value3"}
};

this.myDataGrid.ItemsSource = dictionary;
```

Comment: Please understand my question. It is about search when key down not about how to assign datagrid datasource

Comment: which key specifically?